# Mathematical problem in 1D bosonization

Tags: commutator, many-body, dirac-delta-distributions, bosonization

I am reading the following article on bosonization :
https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9805275

and I encountered the following set of equalities.

$$\begin{align}
[\phi_\eta (x),\partial_{x'}\phi_{\eta'}(x')]&=\delta_{\eta\eta'}\frac{2\pi}{L}\left[\frac{1}{\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{L}(x-x'-ia)\right)-1}+\frac{1}{\exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi}{L}(x-x'+ia)\right)-1}\right]\\
&\xrightarrow{L\rightarrow\infty} \delta_{\eta\eta'}2\pi i \left[\frac{a/\pi}{(x-x')^2+a^2}-\frac{1}{L}\right] \\
&\xrightarrow{a\rightarrow 0} 2\pi i\left[\delta(x-x')-\frac{1}{L}\right]
\end{align}$$
I agree with the first equality but I do not understand where the $\frac{1}{L}$ factor comes from in the limit... Can someone help me, please?

Comment: It's exactly the same $1/L$ that's out front of the square brackets in the first line!

Comment: @d_b I agree that the L comes from the factor above, I just don't see how that term comes out in the sense that I don't understand if the -1 is a term of a taylor expansion....